# Why is GitHub not an option for Azure Web App deployment?

Tags: git, azure, github, deployment

I'm using JetBrains Rider to develop an ASP.NET Core 2.1 web application. The app works in a local development environment.

However, deploying the app to Azure has been quite a challenge. The project is in a private repository on my GitHub account. The tutorials I find online have screenshots that show part of the Azure Portal that I don't see in my portal. For example, the list of deployment sources in one tutorial looks like this:

[image: Deployment options of tutorial]

While in my portal it looks like this:

[image: My deployment options]

I want to deploy from my private GitHub repository, so I select "External Repository" on my screen.

It looks like this:

[image: External git repository configuration]

Whereas the "GitHub" source configuration looks like this in the tutorial:

[image]

The source configuration in my Azure Portal does not seem to support authorization for private repositories. What am I missing?

[The tutorial i'm referring to](https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/17161/Continuous-Deployment-from-GitHub-to-Azure/26574#.W0yZF9j-giU)

Comment: Where are you looking at in the portal and what kind of resource are you trying to deploy to (e.g. App Service)?  Looking at the portal now I see all the options I should (like the tutorial) but my label under Deployment option label says "set up deployment option" while yours says "Setup a deployment source". Might just be a localization subtlety . Are you in your App Service blade in azure under "Deployment Options" ?

Comment: Yes, It is a Web App in the App Service blade

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not a reasonable appearance, even if the OS type of the web app is Linux, there will be the GitHub option.

I think you could try to create a new web app, refer to my steps.

1. Navigate to **App service** in the portal -> **Add** -> **Web App** -> **Create**
2. After creating the web app, check the **Deployment options** and configure it.

**Besides**, you also can use **Deployment Center (Preview)**, it is a preview version, like a Upgraded version of **Deployment options**, it provides the deployment with more details, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-continuous-deployment).

P.S. The MS official documentation of **Continuous deployment** has been already changed from **Deployment options** to **Deployment Center (Preview)**, it is worth a try.

Comment: The problem is that Deployment Center (Preview) is not available / greyed out

Comment: @A.S. Have you created a new web app to have a try?

Comment: Yes I deleted the Web App and re-created it. The issue is unfortunately still there

Comment: @A.S. It is really a strange problem, I recommend you to [contact Azure Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) for help.

Comment: I'm facing this same issue in June 2022. Could it be related to it being an F1 tier App Service (i.e., free)? I don't see anything in the docs or pricing pages saying GitHub is not an option for the free tier, but the only option I have for CII/CD source is "Local Git".